# Convert values (variables) into json object using newtonsoft json

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I have done something like this. But I know this is not the correct way to do it. If anyone can give me some sample code or a documentation link about how this variable convert into JSON object using  Newtonsoft JSON library I will be thankful.

```
Dim ID As Integer = 0
Dim FirstName As String = "Jon"
Dim LastName As String = "Doe"
Dim Department As String = "Finance"


Dim RequestBody As String = "{ ""ID"": """ & ID & """, " &
                            """FirstName "": """ & FirstName & """," &
                            """LastName "": """ & LastName & """," &
                            """Department"": """ & Department & """}"


Dim BodyData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(RequestBody)
Dim result_post = SendRequest(API_URL, BodyData, "application/json", "POST")
```

Comment: When I type *"vb.net convert to json"* I get lots of existing information on the subject. What do you not understand about all the information you found when you did that? You're asking how to use JSON.NET but your code shows no attempt to do so. Until you try it, you don't know that you can't do it and, until you know you can't do it, it's too soon to be posting here.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have read lot of them. most of documents are only explain about c# and most of them not beginner level. I think i need to create a object (class) for those variables and convert into json object. I will try to re-read those documents again. thanks anyway.

Comment: A lot of C# code is actually quite easy to read for a VB developer; even a beginner. For instance, the C# equivalent of what you posted would look almost exactly the same. Some more advanced stuff can be more difficult but becomes easier once you learn certain syntax rules, e.g. Lambda expression syntax in each language. There are also plenty of converters available. Online code converters can be OK but not great. I recommend [Instant VB](https://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/product_details/csharp-to-vb-converter.html), which is excellent, has a free version and is updated regularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest is perhaps to create a new anonymous type and serialize it:

```
Dim ID As Integer = 0
Dim FirstName As String = "Jon"
Dim LastName As String = "Doe"
Dim Department As String = "Finance"

Dim ser = New With { .ID = ID, .FirstName = FirstName, .LastName = LastName, .Department = Department }

Dim RequestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ser)
```

This can of course be reduced to

```
Dim RequestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( _
  New With { _
    .ID = 0, _
    .FirstName = "Jon", _
    .LastName = "Doe", _
    .Department = "Finance" _
  } _
)
```

VB is looking more and more like C# every day! :)

(Here's what it looks like in C#):

```
var RequestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( 
  new { 
    ID = 0, 
    FirstName = "Jon", 
    LastName = "Doe", 
    Department = "Finance" 
  } 
);
```

Definitely worth learning to read C#, if you're a VB programmer - a huge amount of the "stuff you need" is C# because of its popularity and at least being able to read it will give you some good pointers and help

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, in my visual studio 2019 (Version 16.6.4) automatically removed underscore character. So you so much correct about 'VB is looking more and more like C# every day' thanks again.

Comment: With VB these days there are situations where you can omit line continuations and situations where you can't and (as a human) it's easier to just follow a rule of "put line continuations in everywhere you want a line to continue and let visual studio remove them if it wants to" than to try and remember [all the different places where you can or cant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/statements#implicit-line-continuation). Some of the options in that doc are pretty ugly too, in my opinion.